# Database connection problem encountered using d2rq

Tags: mysql, jdbc, rdf, d2rq

When I convert the data in MySQL into RDF, when using generate-mapping -u root -p 123456 -o kg_demo_movie_mapping.ttl "jdbc:mysql:///kg_demo_movie?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC" I report an error.Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is` com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.Database exception (E0) .
My MySQL version is 8.0.11. According to the Internet, I still report the same error when I put the jar package of 5.1.47 under d2rq / lib,I don't know what i can do now,thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

That message is a bit puzzling.  Part of it is seems to be saying that the application that you are using is explicitly loading the JDBC driver ... which is deprecated<sup>1</sup>.  But it is also saying that you (it) should be using MySQL Connector/J 8.x JDBC drivers rather than the `5.1.47` JAR in the `d2rq` library directory.  (You can get MySQL Connector/J 8.x drivers from the download site.)

Basically, it looks like you are using out-of-date / abandoned software.  The [github site for dr2q](https://github.com/d2rq/d2rq) shows no changes on the master branch since 2015.  And the repo is now read-only.

If you had sufficient Java programming skill and were willing to put in the effort, you could:

- Fork the repo
- Investigate the real cause of the problem<sup>2</sup>
- Update the codebase to fix the apparent `Class::forName` issue and/or upgrade the JDBC driver.

But if you don't have the skills, etcetera ... your best bet would be to look for another tool.  (You may be able to find a hacky workaround for this problem on some other forum ... only to be stumped by the next one.)

---

<sup>1 - It should be using `DriverManager` ... which will discover the JDBC drivers automatically.  Using `Class::forName` to load the driver has not been necessary since Java 5.0.

2 - Don't count on someone else doing that work for you, for free.</sup>

Comment: ok,thank you,i will look for another answer